# Xamarin - Accent symbol in es.strings file preventing compiling?

Tags: ios, xamarin, localization, mono, xamarin.ios

Am I doing this correctly? I want to include Spanish translations in my iOS app but I'm getting a compile error. I want to check if I'm doing this right or not.

**How to reproduce my problem:**

1. In your iOS project, create a folder called "Resources".
2. Inside of the Resources folder, create another folder called "es.lproj".
3. Inside of the es.lproj folder, add a file named "Localizable.strings".
4. In that file add: `"connection" = "Conexión";`
5. Build and you will get this error:
   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: Resources/es.lproj/Localizable.strings: Property List error: Unexpected character " at line 1 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
6. Replace the accented "o" with just a regular "o" and build again. No errors.

**Versions**

- Xamarin: 5.10.1
- Xamarin.iOS: 9.4.0.0

Does this happen to anyone else?

Comment: Just tried using Xamarin.iOS Version: 9.4.1.24 and it compiles fine.

Comment: It compiles fine on Xamarin Studio 5.10.2 and Xamarion.iOS 9.4.1.24 on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: My guessing is that the encoding for the file is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mgChristopher was correct. Somehow Localizable.strings had the wrong encoding.

The solution was to simply delete the file and recreate it. Once I pasted in the original content it built and ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when you are using xamarin studio and copying the data into it, i ran into the same problem when tried to copy the data from other sources and just paste it here, the best option for now to do is create a .strings file in xamarin studio and then try to add each conversion manually, should help.